# Как заставить программу принимать любой тип данных через одну переменную? с++

Tags: c++

Самое банальное что я пытался сделать было:

```
auto x;
cout << x;
```

Код не запустился и показывал ошибку.
Тогда я попытался:

```
unsigned x;
cin >> x;
cout << x;
```

Код в этот раз запустился но при вводе чисел с плавающей запятой возвращает округленное значение.
ПРИМЕР: 14.4 Вывод в консоли:14

Comment: А строку читать? Как компилятор в compile-time может угадать, к какому типу может быть отнесена введенная строка, и сгенерировать соответствующий код?

Comment: C++ — язык *строго типизированный*.

Comment: Строку можно, только вычислять с ней нельзя. В теории можно ли вообще заставить переменную принимать ввод любых чисел или нет? Видимо нельзя.

Comment: *"строго типизированный"* означает, что тип всех переменных, и вообще всех вычисляемых выражений, однозначно фиксируется во время компиляции. одна переменная = один тип данных С другой стороны, вам никто не мешает поверх этого написать объектную модель с динамической типизацией и получить свой c# / java / java script / python / php и т. п.

Comment: Чаще всего используют `std::variant`, но тогда список типов нужно указать заранее, и самому сделать логику определения того, какой тип ввели.